# Microsoft Excel replace data from cells from a different cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to make the substitute function target cells that the formula isn't written in.

So an example would be cell A1 contains "A" but when cell B1 contains "A" cell A1 changes to "x"

The substitute function does this but I want to be able use the formula typed in a cell of my choosing.

Comment: give an extensive example with screenshot and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

No function can change a value in another cell. Functions only return values to the cell in which they reside. You need to change the cell manually or with VBA, or better yet, revise your data architecture to work with Excel, not against it.